# How to write PDDL Domain and Problem file?

Tags: planning, pddl

I am trying to do some planing project by using PDDL. I want to do from some natural text. Like:

1. Take the knife from left to right hand.
2. Cut the apple.
3. Wash knife.

I am confused abut the predicates and action. how to defined the predicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predicates are the things that can be true or false in a state of the environment. E.g., `(holding ?hand ?item)`.

Actions would be the things that change the world. E.g., `take`, `cut`, `wash`.